# Python load CSV into list and run regex on items

Tags: python, regex

I am reading a CSV file into a list using python like this..

```
    with open(myfile) as csvfile:
        readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        postcode_list = []
    for row in readCSV:
        postcode = row[0]
        postcode_list.append(postcode)
```

This works correctly and I end up with a list of all the postcodes.  I also have a regex statement which checks postcodes to ensure they are properly formed

```
^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2}[A-Z]?s[0-9][A-Z][A-Z]$
```

I am trying to get an error to display if a postcode does not match the regex.  Do I need to iterate over my list to do this or is there a way I can do it during the CSV to List conversion?

Comment: Just a little improvement in regex. `^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2}[A-Z]?s[0-9][A-Z]{2}$`

Comment: I can see the change but can you explain the improvement?

Comment: Depends on if you want to bail out if an invalid code is found. For that, check  before you add to list. If not, still check before you add it to the list, but add the _bad_ index to another list. This way you have a bad list of indexes.

Comment: Is your indentation correct?

Comment: Wanted it to fail as soon as it finds the first non-matching postcode

Comment: Either way, do the regex just before your append statement.

Comment: @fightstarr20: Just removed last `[A-Z]` and added `{2}`. Makes sense right ?

Comment: @noob - `[A-Z][A-Z]` is quicker than `[A-Z]{2}`, so it's not really a speed improvement. Yeah, the first one is actually up to twice as fast.

Comment: You can definitely perform sanity check during CSV to list conversion. I'm not sure what exactly your intention is but you can break loop if you find any problem, print message and exit.

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your second `for` loop. Create a Python pattern matching object from the `re` module. Use instance method `match(string)` to match the postcode. If that method returns true, there is a match, and the postcode being examined should be appended to `postcode_list`. If match returns false, `break`.

Create the matching object outside of the `for` loop to avoid costly instantiation and garbage collection--it takes time to build regex automata.